# Testing AppClip with local experience issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-appclips, apple-app-site-association

I am trying to test an `AppClip` on my device by scanning the QR code.

Apple suggested:

> Next, on the device, open the Settings app, navigate to Developer >
> Local Experiences, and select Register Local Experience. Configure a
> local experience and enter:
> A URL prefix that invokes the app clip
> Copy for the app clip card’s title and the subtitle
> A call-to-action verb
> A header image
> Your app clip’s bundle identifier

But I can't find `Developer` -> `Local Experience` option on my device. I am using beta version of iOS 14 (beta 6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you needed to connect the phone to my computer and let Xcode initialise it as a development device on my account. If still not appears restart the device and keep connected with Xcode .

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your phone is connected to XCode and declared as a development device to even see the `Development` section in the `Settings` app.
2. Make sure you use a more modern device as I've seen some older devices not displaying the `Local Experience` option even though they are set as Development devices and support `QR` and `NFC`